# I Keep Getting Invalid datetime format: 1292

Tags: mysql, laravel, api, laravel-8

Model

```
class ClickMeeting extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'clickmeeting';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $dateFormat = 'U';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    static $videoDemoSource = ['upload', 'youtube', 'vimeo', 'external_link'];

    public function ClickMeeting()
    {
        ///
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public function dashboard()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $uri = 'https://api.clickmeeting.com/v1/conferences/active';
        $header = ['headers' => ['X-Api-Key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']];
        $res = $client->get($uri, $header);
        $conferences = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);

        // dd($conferences);

        collect($conferences)
            ->each(function ($conference, $key) {
                ClickMeeting::firstOrCreate([
                    'parent_id' => $conference['parent_id'],
                    'room_type' => $conference['room_type'],
                    'room_url' => $conference['room_url'],
                    
                ],
                [
                    'starts_at' => $conference['starts_at'],
                    'ends_at' => $conference['ends_at'],
                    'room_pin' => $conference['room_pin'],
                    'title' => $conference['name'],
                    'name_url' => $conference['name_url'],
                    'access_type' => $conference['access_type'],
                    'lobby_enabled' => $conference['lobby_enabled'],
                    'lobby_description' => $conference['lobby_description'],
                    'registration_enabled' => $conference['registration_enabled'],
                    'status' => $conference['status'],
                    'timezone' => $conference['timezone'],
                    'timezone_offset' => $conference['timezone_offset'],
                    'paid_enabled' => $conference['paid_enabled'],
                    'automated_enabled' => $conference['automated_enabled'],
                    'type' => $conference['type'],
                    'permanent_room' => $conference['permanent_room'],
                    'embed_room_url' => $conference['embed_room_url']
                ]);
            });

        $conferences = ClickMeeting::get();

        return view('admin.clickmeeting.dashboard',compact('conferences'));
```

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime
> value: '2022-06-22T16:10:00+00:00' for column 'starts_at' at row 1
> (SQL: insert into `clickmeeting` (`parent_id`, `room_type`,
> `room_url`, `starts_at`, `ends_at`, `room_pin`, `title`, `name_url`,
> `access_type`, `lobby_enabled`, `lobby_description`,
> `registration_enabled`, `status`, `timezone`, `timezone_offset`,
> `paid_enabled`, `automated_enabled`, `type`, `permanent_room`,
> `embed_room_url`) values (?, webinar,
> https://abc.clickmeeting.com/urinary-tract-infection-in-children,
> 2022-06-22T16:10:00+00:00, 2022-06-22T17:10:00+00:00, 477736894,
> URINARY TRACT INFECTION IN CHILDREN,
> urinary-tract-infection-in-children, 1, 1, , 1, active, Africa/Accra,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> https://abc.clickwebinar.com/embed_conference.html?r=123456))

I keep getting Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value. Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: if you are using laravel, all dates should use [`Carbon\Carbon`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting) instance for less headache.

Answer (score 0):

I think these occur because the DATETIME value in the statement above uses a format that is not supported by MySQL, you can use the STR_TO_DATE() function for passing the starts_at variable into the database.

**The code like**

```
'starts_at' => STR_TO_DATE($conference['starts_at'], "%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s"),
```

[Please check this link you can find more about the STR_TO_DATE() function](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try use [`Carbon\Carbon`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for assigning your dates:

```
collect($conferences)
    ->each(function ($conference, $key) {
          ClickMeeting::firstOrCreate([
            ....
          ],
          [
            'starts_at' => Carbon::parse($conference['starts_at']),
            'ends_at' => Carbon::parse($conference['ends_at']),
            ....
          ]);
    });
```

Alternatively, you could tell laravel which fields are date using the [`$casts` property](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting):

```
class ClickMeeting extends Model
{
    ....
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $casts = [
          'starts_at' => 'datetime',
          'ends_at' => 'datetime'
    ];
    ....
}
```